# How to know Typing Status in XMPP openfire using Smack

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack, asmack

I am developing chat application by using Openfire XMPP server. I can text chat between two user. But i want to know Typing status when some one is typing message. So i created a class :-

```
public class typingStatus implements ChatStateListener {

    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat arg0, Message arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(Chat arg0, ChatState arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(arg0.getParticipant() + " is " + arg1.name());

    }

}
```

But i am confuse so that How will it work?  I know that i need a packet where i can it in Listener. But i am unable to find that packet.

Please any one suggest, How will it work?

and also what is difference between Smack and asmack?

Thank you!

Comment: Kindly check this question in Stackoverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154833/how-to-get-typing-status-notification-in-xmpp

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To enable `ChatStateListener` you need to create a custom `MessageListener` Class

```
public class MessageListenerImpl implements MessageListener,ChatStateListener  {

    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat arg0, Message arg1) {
        System.out.println("Received message: " + arg1);

    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(Chat arg0, ChatState arg1) {
        if (ChatState.composing.equals(arg1)) {
            Log.d("Chat State",arg0.getParticipant() + " is typing..");
        } else if (ChatState.gone.equals(arg1)) {
            Log.d("Chat State",arg0.getParticipant() + " has left the conversation.");
        } else {
            Log.d("Chat State",arg0.getParticipant() + ": " + arg1.name());
        }

    }

}
```

Then you create `MessageListener` object

```
MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListenerImpl();
```

And then pass this in the create chat method

```
Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat(jabber_id_of_friend, messageListener);
```

**what is difference between Smack and asmack?** <-- [Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15575750/983741)

Comment: Thank you sunil. looking good and gave me solution. I will check.

Comment: no userID is the jid of the other participant, not the one who logged in

Comment: thank you sunil. if you have a bit time. please check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437329/how-to-know-message-send-status-not-send-delivery-read-like-as-whatsapp?noredirect=1#comment27090174_18437329

Comment: To handle message events look at this http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/messageevents.html

Comment: i checked but did not get stateChanged. plz suggest

Comment: please check, It is not working ,i am still unable to get typing status .

Comment: are you sending composing status from the other end?

Comment: sry, i am just using this code. i think, i should use focusonEditText and when user will typing, it will send a composing status. do you have any example ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36299/discussion-between-sunil-mishra-and-user2160008)

Comment: @SunilMishra getting error on Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat(jabber_id_of_friend, messageListener);..can u please explain this line? It shows red line with error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method createChat(String, MessageListener) from the type ChatManager`

Comment: @geet createChat is not a static method, you need an instance of ChatManager to invoke that method

Comment: It did not work on openfire. type notification need XEP-0085: Chat State Notifications, BUT THE OPENFIRE DOSE NOT HAVE THIS XEP. 
Any other suggestion except changing openfire?

Comment: Its not working any other solution to get user status..?

Answer (score 4):

finally I got the solution. I need to use chat listener along with chat manager and also I need to use in built ***sendcomposingnotification*** function. No need to use Messageeventrequestlistener interface or any other custom class for this. I added the following lines,,

```
connection.getChatManager().addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener() {

            @Override
            public void chatCreated(final Chat arg0, final boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                arg0.addMessageListener(new MessageListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void processMessage(Chat arg0, Message arg1) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Log.d("TYpe Stat",title[0] + " is typing......");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),title[0] + " is typing......",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }



                    }
                }); 
            }
        });
```

and also need to send notification like this..

```
mem.sendComposingNotification(etRecipient.getText().toString(), message.getPacketID());
        System.out.println("Sending notification");
```

where mem is type of MessageEventManger.
Ref: http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/MessageEventManager.html

Comment: hi i tried above..but not working! here is my code! any help will be appreciated.......                                                  Message msg1 = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);

            msg1.setFrom("user1@192.168.0.98"); // my id

            MessageEventManager event=new MessageEventManager(connection);
              //recipient id
            event.sendComposingNotification("tech1@192.168.0.98",msg1.getPacketId());

Comment: @Aneez, you need to process the message received in the ````processMessage()```` , because it receives all the incoming packets, not only the ````typing```` status. It might be paused, offline/online status packets, or messages.. so try to process it and then handle..

Comment: Hi. I tried the same but it did'nt work for me..it neither sendComposingNotification nor receiving it. gives me null at receiving and while received it from ios.
Help me to find out this.
Thank you.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154833/how-to-get-typing-status-notification-in-xmpp

Answer (score 2):

```
ChatManager chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
Chat chat= chatManager.createChat(to, new ChatStateListener() {
      @Override
      public void stateChanged(Chat chat, ChatState state) {
                switch (state){
                        case active:
                             Log.d("state","active");
                             break;
                        case composing:
                             Log.d("state","composing");
                             break;
                        case paused:
                             Log.d("state","paused");
                             break;
                        case inactive:
                             Log.d("state","inactive");
                             break;
                        case gone:
                             Log.d("state","gone");
                             break;
                 }
        }

        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
               Log.d("processMessage","processMessage");
        }
});
```

use this code.hope so will work

Comment: Hello, Ahesanali Momin,
can you please let me know exact scenario at your end.and what kind of error you are facing in XMPP. for more info message me at skype @ piyush.gupta326. then we can discuss more,your problem and hopefully will reach success point.

Comment: I am not getting any error but when i start tyoping code doesn't enter in any state, i mean stateChangeListener not called.

Comment: hey man,
have you read this doc http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html

Comment: this is completely theory and not interesting as of now, as most of the things pretty clear by using chat client.

Comment: I meant, please read the documentation in that link. I hope you will found the solution there. else we can discuss same here.

Comment: Should i have to add something while sending message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117163/discussion-between-ahesanali-momin-and-piyushgupta202390).

Comment: It was my mistake that i am not sending composing status when user starts typing and send other status when stops typing. But chatstate listener you have mentioned is perfact.

Answer (score 1):

i am using chat state listener :

```
Chat chat = chatManager.createChat(jid,
                        new ChatStateChangedListener());
```

bind the chatstatelistener with each jid like above , then :

```
public class ChatStateChangedListener implements ChatStateListener {

    public ChatStateChangedListener() {
        printLog("Chat State Changed Listner Constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat arg0, Message arg1) {

    }


    @Override
    public void stateChanged(Chat chat, ChatState state) {

        if (state.toString().equals(ChatState.composing.toString())) {
                tvLastSeen.setText("Typing...");
            } else if (state.toString().equals(ChatState.paused.toString())) {
                tvLastSeen.setText("paused...");
            } else {
                tvLastSeen.setText("nothing");
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154833/how-to-get-typing-status-notification-in-xmpp

Answer (score 1):

**Create On Class MMessageListener to listen incoming messages**

private class MMessageListener implements MessageListener, ChatStateListener {

```
    public MMessageListener(Context contxt) {
    }


    @Override
    public void stateChanged(Chat chat, ChatState chatState) {

        mStatus = "Online";

        if (ChatState.composing.equals(chatState)) {

            mStatus = chat.getParticipant() + " is typing..";
            Log.d("Chat State", chat.getParticipant() + " is typing..");
        } else if (ChatState.gone.equals(chatState)) {
            Log.d("Chat State", chat.getParticipant() + " has left the conversation.");
            mStatus = chat.getParticipant() + " has left the conversation.";
        } else if (ChatState.paused.equals(chatState)){
            Log.d("Chat State", chat.getParticipant() + ": " + chatState.name());
            mStatus = "Paused";
        }else if (ChatState.active.equals(chatState)){
            mStatus = "Online";
        }

        // do whatever you want to do once you receive status


    }


    @Override
    public void processMessage(Message message) {

    }

    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {


    }
}
```

**Add Listener to your chat object**

Chat Mychat = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).createChat(
                    "user2@localhost"),
                    mMessageListener);

**Send status to receiving user on edittext text change**

ChatStateManager.getInstance(connection).setCurrentState(ChatState.composing, Mychat);

This works fine for me.

Comment: Hi Dharmesh, i did the same but i am getting null always in composing state message in processMessage. 
My EditText text change method is : 
 newChat = chatmanager.createChat(send_to, messageListener);
                        Message msg = new Message(send_to,
                                Message.Type.chat);
                        msg.setFrom(USERNAME_LOGIN+"@"+HOST_NAME); // my id
                        newChat.sendMessage(msg);
                        ChatStateManager.getInstance(connection).setCurrentState(ChatState.composing, newChat);
And this also not send status to others.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154833/how-to-get-typing-status-notification-in-xmpp

Comment: How to check if user has paused or is no longer typing in the editext?

Answer (score 0):

Your or another xmpp client which you use, should sending chat state for You can catch the state.

Like This;

```
try {
      ChatStateManager.getInstance(GlobalVariables.xmppManager.connection).setCurrentState(ChatState.composing, chat);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

or

```
try {
        ChatStateManager.getInstance(GlobalVariables.xmppManager.connection).setCurrentState(ChatState.gone, chat);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe your Server application doesnt support it.

Comment: you mean to say our server is not configure for that ? but its working fine with ios to ios.
i am writting this line on textChangeListner of EditText.
and chat object is 
chatmanager = connection.getChatManager();
    Chat chat = chatmanager.createChat("user@", listner);
Even when i receive compose status from ios processMessage gives me null.
Please help me to find solution for both send and receive.
P.S. i am using asmack library

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225394/how-to-get-the-typing-status-in-asmack-android

Comment: This needs to be done on editext text text change listener..right?

Answer (score 0):

However you can get it from ProcessPacket also.
there you will get a Message object, after you can extract xml portion from there and handle them its contain specific chatstate or not.

```
    Message message = (Message) packet;
    String msg_xml = message.toXML().toString();

    if (msg_xml.contains(ChatState.composing.toString())) {
        //handle is-typing, probably some indication on screen
    } else if (msg_xml.contains(ChatState.paused.toString())) {
        // handle "stopped typing"
    } else {
       // normal msg
    }
```

now handle as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ChatStateManager` after `ChatManager` intalization:

```
chatManager =  ChatManager.getInstanceFor(getXmpptcpConnection());
ChatStateManager.getInstance(getXmpptcpConnection());
```

Then you need to add `ChatStateListener` during `createChat(to,chatMesageListener)`:

```
chatManager.createChat(message.getTo(), chatMessageListener).sendMessage(message);

private ChatStateListener chatMessageListener = new ChatStateListener() {

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(Chat chat, ChatState state) {
        //State Change composing,active,paused,gone,etc
        Log.d(TAG, "ChatStateListener:::stateChanged -> " + chat.toString() + " \n -> " + state.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
        //Incoming Message
        Log.d(TAG, "ChatStateListener:::processMessage -> " + chat.toString() + " \n -> " + message.toString());
    }
};
```

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225394/how-to-get-the-typing-status-in-asmack-android

Comment: Next time, maybe just answer one question and flag the rest to let us know that they're duplicates; posting the same answer 7 times is pretty excessive.