# how to get the typing status in asmack android

Tags: xmpp, smack, asmack

i did the following but am not getting any typing idle status i need a lot of help on xmpp if someone can help me do this

```
public class MessageListenerImpl implements MessageListener,ChatStateListener  {
    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat arg0, Message arg1) {
        System.out.println("Received message: " + arg1);

    }
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(Chat chat, ChatState state) {
        if (ChatState.composing.equals(chat)) {
            Log.DEBUG("Chat State",chat.getParticipant() + " is typing..");
        } else if (ChatState.gone.equals(chat)) {
            Log.DEBUG("Chat State",chat.getParticipant() + " has left the conversation.");
        } else {
            Log.DEBUG("Chat State",chat.getParticipant() + ": " + state.name());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436546/how-to-know-typing-status-in-xmpp-openfire-using-smack